# error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression

Tags: c++

Just for the sake of experimenting, I was implementing a wrapper class that would allocate its payload on the heap and could allow its use implicitly, without using any dereference operator. I came to the following implementation of fictitious class `dynamic` and was happy it could also be used with compound types.

https://godbolt.org/z/rz6nWGYfe
(any comment or improvement is welcome)

Later I was trying to replace `new`/`delete` using an `unique_ptr`, but compound type initialization fails with `error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression`

https://godbolt.org/z/K5vjjs7P1

How to solve?

---

First version using `new`/`delete`

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct dynamic {
    explicit dynamic(const T& value = T{}) { ptr = new T{value}; }

    template <typename... Args>
    dynamic(Args&&... args) {
        ptr = new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }

    ~dynamic() { delete ptr; }

    operator T&() { return *ptr; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr; }

   private:
    T* ptr;
};



struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    dynamic<int> i = 123;   // implicit initialization
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // implicit use

    dynamic<Point> p{1, 2}; // initialization of a compound type
    std::cout << ((Point&)p).x << ' ' << p->y << '\n'; // access to compound type members

    return 0;
}
```

---

Second version using `unique_ptr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct dynamic {
    explicit dynamic(const T& value = T{}) {
        ptr = std::make_unique<T>(value);
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    dynamic(Args&&... args) {
        ptr = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    operator T&() { return *ptr; }
    T* operator->() {
        return ptr.get();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};



struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    dynamic<int> i = 123;   // implicit initialization
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // implicit use

    dynamic<Point> p{1, 2}; // initialization of a compound type
    std::cout << ((Point&)p).x << ' ' << p->y << '\n'; // access to compound type members

    return 0;
}
```

Error message in the `unique_ptr` version:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:1065:30: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
 1065 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:1065:30: error: no matching function for call to 'Point::Point(int)'
```

Comment: Self contained questions please ([mcve])! Godbolt links are decorations at best.

Comment: Try to add `-std=c++20` (if you can use c++20).

Comment: @wohlstad it works, pls make it an answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ made a self containerizing edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in c++17 (or below) there is no implicit constructor for initializing the members via `make_unique` (although you can initialize an object with aggregate-initialization).
MSVC hints to it in the error message related to the `make_unique` line:

```
error C2661: 'Point::Point': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
...
```

You can solve it by adding a **constructor** to `Point` accepting 2 arguments:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x_, int y_) :
        x(x_), y(y_) {}
};
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n1eK91v56)

Or if you can use **c++20**, your code will compile as is (use `-std=c++20` compiler option).

Comment: Great! Thanks to your hints, I was able to found also [related documentation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html).